# Python format leading zeros and thousands comma

Tags: python

I know that I can use the following to pad leading zeros to a string:

```
>>> qty = 1
>>> '{:06}'.format(qty)
'000001'
```

But can I also **use the format function** to also add thousands separators to get:

```
'000,001'
```

I know this can be done by manipulating the text, but can it be achieved with the format() function ?

Comment: add a [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to the documentation - available for 2.7 and above

Comment: Input:  `'{:,}'.format(1234567890)`
Output: `'1,234,567,890'`

Comment: @swatchai Thanks, but as in my post above, I need leading zeros

Comment: `'{:06,}'.format(qty)`  -> ` '00,001'`